# possible to use vpython in ipython notebook?

Tags: ipython, vpython

Whenever I use vpython in ipython the kernel will die. is there any solution? I don't know what to do. (My OS is ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, the browser is firefox.)

Comment: Can you provide more information about how the kernel dies?  A code example that causes it to crash?

Comment: were you able to use vpython in ipython notebook?